# Modify Code - Find & Replace - Google Sheets / Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The below code will find **NAME 1** and replace it with **NM1** as per the  replaceInSheet line of code

I would like the code to look at a list of data in SHEET 2 to do the Find&Replace IN SHEET 1. So Column A has names and is repalced by what is in Column B

[image]

```
function runReplaceInSheet() {

var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(""); // UPDATE ID
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheets()[0]); // UPDATE number in square 
brackets
var range = sheet.getRange("F2:F");
//  get the current data range values as an array
//  Lesser calls to access the sheet, lower overhead 
var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process. start at Row 3
var numRows = 2; // Specify what column to look at. 
// Fetch the range of cells 
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 150 , numRows, 1) // Numbers of rows to process
// Fetch values for each row in the Range
var data = dataRange.getValues();
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
var row = data[i];
var v = row[2]; // edit: don't need this
var values = range.getValues();  



replaceInSheet(values, 'Name 1', 'N1');
replaceInSheet(values, 'Name 2', 'N2');

//write the updated values to the sheet, again less call;less overhead
range.setValues(values);
```

}
}

```
 function replaceInSheet(values, to_replace, replace_with) {

 //loop over the rows in the array
 for (var row in values) {

//use Array.map to execute a replace call on each of the cells in the row.
var replaced_values = values[row].map(function(original_value) {
    return original_value.toString().replace(to_replace, replace_with);
});

//replace the original row values with the replaced values
values[row] = replaced_values;
}}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `I would like the code to look at a list of data in SHEET 2 to do the Find&Replace IN SHEET 1. So Column A has names and is repalced by what is in Column B` and your sample image. In order to correctly understand about your current issue and goal, can you provide the sample input and output you expect?

Comment: Tanaike i will share a sheet with you

Comment: Thank you for replying. I thought that when the sample input and output you expect might help to understand about your current situation and goal.

Comment: here is first spreadsheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/187uMv_PQeQQ7YQqd8VqnGkLC0fWUja7JXelkvz1mb3M/edit#gid=0

Comment: here is 2nd link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PfqPcn5NhCjj2Ukbb2MZh9xTFz0w8YAbX3_WIKHwSrU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: if you run the code tyou will see name changes in D2D Sheet From Master - Agency Name Change

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I saw your sample Spreadsheets, I thought that your question might be different from your samples. So I cannot understand about what you want to do. I apologize for this. Can you explain about your current issue and goal? If you think that your question is required to be updated, please do it.

Comment: modify this code replaceInSheet(values, 'Name 1', 'N1'); to read from sheet 2. sheet 2 listkeeps changinging. otherwise i have to keep changing the replaceinsheets

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot still understand about what you want to do. But I would like to try to understand about it. So can you give me a time to do it? If you can do, I'm glad.

Comment: このコードを変換できますreplaceInSheet（values、 'Name 1'、 'N1'）;シート2のデータのリストから読み取るため。このリストに新しい名前を追加し続ける必要があるため

Comment: 名前のリストが追加され続け、毎回コードを追加し続けたくありません

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your goal, 1. you want to retrieve the values of columns "A" and "B" of "Replace Agency Name" in "Master - Agency Name Change". 2. You want to change the column "F" of "D2D MACRO" in "D2D Macro" by the column "B" corresponding to the column "A" of "Replace Agency Name". Is my understanding correct?

Comment: yes Tanaike that is correct

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed the modified scripts as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If those were not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: tanaike - the script worked perfect. i am always greatful for your help

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I could understand your question by your cooperation. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

1. You want to retrieve the values of columns "A" and "B" of "Replace Agency Name" in "Master - Agency Name Change".
2. You want to change the column "F" of "D2D MACRO" in "D2D Macro" by the column "B" corresponding to the column "A" of "Replace Agency Name".

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `getValues()` is used in the loop. In this case, the process cost will become high.
- The values for replacing are directly used in the script.

From above situation, I would like to propose the following flow.

1. Retrieve values for replacing are retrieved as the source values from the sheet "Replace Agency Name" in "Master - Agency Name Change".
2. Replace the values using the retrieved source values.

#### Sample script 1:

In this sample script, the values are replaced by `setValues`.

```
function myFunction() {
  // 1. Retrieve values for replacing are retrieved as the source values from the sheet "Replace Agency Name" in "Master - Agency Name Change".
  var srcSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("###").getSheetByName("Replace Agency Name");
  var srcValues = srcSheet.getRange(`A2:B${srcSheet.getLastRow()}`).getValues();
  var srcObj = srcValues.reduce((o, [a, b]) => Object.assign(o, {[a]: b}), {});
  
  // 2. Replace the values using the retrieved source values.
  var dstSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("D2D MACRO");
  var dstRange = dstSheet.getRange(`F2:F${dstSheet.getLastRow()}`);
  var dstValues = dstRange.getValues().map(([f]) => [srcObj[f] || f]);
  dstRange.setValues(dstValues);
}
```

#### Sample script 2:

In this sample script, the values are replaced by `TextFinder`.

```
function myFunction() {
  // 1. Retrieve values for replacing are retrieved as the source values from the sheet "Replace Agency Name" in "Master - Agency Name Change".
  var srcSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("###").getSheetByName("Replace Agency Name");
  var srcValues = srcSheet.getRange(`A2:B${srcSheet.getLastRow()}`).getValues();
  var dstSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("D2D MACRO");

  // 2. Replace the values using the retrieved source values.
  var dstRange = dstSheet.getRange(`F2:F${dstSheet.getLastRow()}`);
  srcValues.forEach(([a, b]) => {
    if (a.toString() != "") dstRange.createTextFinder(a).matchEntireCell(true).replaceAllWith(b)
  });
}
```

#### Note:

- In above scripts, `srcSheet` is "Replace Agency Name" in "Master - Agency Name Change". And `dstSheet` is "D2D MACRO" of the active Spreadsheet. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [Class TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)